# dont send empty field text from contact from 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I designed a service order form on WordPress using the Form 7 contact. How can I prevent unsolicited fields from being sent to email?
I put the title of the fields inside the div tags. I wrote the title of the service in the text of the email.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span style="padding-bottom: 2em;"></span>
        <span class="products">test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="qty-count qty-count--order">
            <span class="count-reduce">–</span>
            [text bedrooms class:count-input "0"]
            <span class="count-add">+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

test 1>>name product
[text bedrooms class:count-input "0"]>>counter product

Comment: Please share detailed information or screenshot

Comment: information share@Ravi